# How to configure to immediately compression the image when received it in the dcm4chee

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

All , Forgive me I just began to learn dcm4chee. I just read the dcm4chee Compression Service from the [WiKi](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Compression+Service). It said that `The Compression Service supports delayed, lossless compression of received images. This is an alternative to immediately compressing images when received.`
So I knew the Compression rule can trigger a delayed compression of received image.

But I wondered How to make it to immediately compression the image when dch4chee received the image. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameter of the StoreScp service (so in jmx console, look for service=StoreScp) and then set the CompressionRules attribute (e.g.: JPLL
 will automatically - and immediately - compress images as JPEG Lossless).
See https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Storage+SCP

Comment: Wonderful! I will try it out .Thanks.

Comment: My dcm4chee does not work. Any plugin or java classes to add.